# "Importing test library 'Selenium2Library' failed: ImportError: No module named decorator" RobotFramework maven plugin

Tags: java, python, maven, intellij-idea, robotframework

Attempting to run a simple test in a Maven Java Project in IntelliJ 2016.2 on OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 using RobotFramework-Maven-Plugin 1.4.6

http://robotframework.org/MavenPlugin/

If the test is run using robot through command line the test opens a firefox browser, runs and passes:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library
Suite Teardown  Close all browsers

*** Variables ***
${BROWSER}  firefox
${DOMAIN}  google.com
${PAGE_TITLE}  google

*** Test Cases ***
Example
  Open browser  http://${DOMAIN}  ${BROWSER}
  Page Should Contain  ${PAGE_TITLE}
```

Here's the error I'm receiving:

```
Importing test library 'Selenium2Library' failed: ImportError: No module named decorator
```

Here the important part of my pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>robotframework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.markusbernhardt</groupId>
        <artifactId>robotframework-selenium2library-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have the latest Selenium2Library 1.8.0 under /src/test/resources/robotframework/libraries/ as prescribed by the RobotFramework Maven Plugin site: http://robotframework.org/MavenPlugin/examples/seleniumlibrary.html

I've been at this problem all day and have searched and finally hit a dead end. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have  you tried installing the `decorator` package?

Comment: The whole idea of the RobotFramework Maven Plugin is to be able to use Robot Framework in a Maven project without the need to install anything extra, to leverage the dependency management of Maven. Having to install the decorator package would contradict the whole point of using the plugin. So I would assume there's some configuration issue on my part that I was hoping would be glaring to someone with expertise in this area.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what I was doing wrong, I still don't have running tests but I'm past this issue. Basically if you're using the RobotFramework Selenium2Library java port, you no longer need to follow the directions on the site about having the Selenium2Library under /src/test/resources/robotframework/libaries

You don't need to have the Selenium2Library in your resources dir, it's taken care of by the maven dependency.

Comment: As long as you are not using Java8, then it just doesn't work the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Just download it through pip3

pip3 install robotframework-seleniumlibrary